# Converting 3D point to 2D pixel position using callibration data

Tags: lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

I'm in the process of registering a camera image from a GoPro to a mesh generated from a lidar scanner. For this I need to transform a 3D point in the camera frame to a 2D pixel point in the image. I've found the calibration data for the camera using the camera_calibration package and I've found this page:

http://wiki.ros.org/image_pipeline/CameraInfo
Which describes the transformations I'm looking for, however I don't understand the notation used in section 3 to describe the actual vector operations to achieve the transformation I need.

Is there a package which encapsulates this transformation? Or can someone explain what:

X' = [R,t]X   transform

sx = X'       projection

x* = d(x)     distortion

q  = Kx*      pixel coordinates

means in terms of vector operations.

Thanks,
Pete

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222764/converting-3d-point-to-2d-pixel-position-using-callibration-data/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-12-18**:
I'm pretty sure there is a package, but I can't come up with the name right now.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-12-18**:
You probably should also take into account that several 3d points will be projected onto the same pixel. As your camera and the lidar do not have the same position, you will have only project visible points into the camera and not the points that are occluded by other 3d objects.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2015-12-18**:
There's the image_proc package, but that only seems to produce a rectilinear image from the distorted wide angle image. I need a function to transform 3D points directly, I may have to dig into the source files for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to project points into the image, you can use the pinhole_camera_model-class:

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#a30b3761aadfa4b91c7fedb97442c2f13

cv::Point2d image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel::project3dToPixel    (   const cv::Point3d &     xyz )   const

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2015-12-18**:
Great, that looks perfect. I'll give it a go in a few hours and let you know how I get on.
Thanks.